# Why I can't merge two inequalities?

Tags: c, comparison, cs50

Well I'm going through CS50 right now and I'm trying to do the Mario project. I'm at the beginning of the code and this happens:

```c
#include<cs50.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    do 
    {
       x = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    while( x < 1 && x > 8);
}
```

I want the user to input a number between 1 and 8 included and that's it but the program says overlapping comparisons always evaluate to false.

What should I do ?

Comment: Check your while condition, it only runs if x is below 1 and above 8, that's not valid condition. I guess you mean: x >= 1 && x <= 8

Answer (score 2):

you are checking if `x is smaller than 1` **and** `x is bigger than 8`.

I think you want `x < 1 || x > 8` (same condition, but with `OR`).
i.e., continue asking for a number until it is in range.